# How can I create a number at the middle of my text so I can reference them?

Tags: latex

I need to put numbers (the numbers must be generated automatically) inside circles for some of the sentences in my text in a way that I could label them and reference them later.

I already made the circle and label.

```
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

 \let\oldlabelenumi=\labelenumi
 \begin{enumerate}
 \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\circled{\oldlabelenumi}}


  \item \label{A}This is a  sample.  This sentence should \item \label{B} 
   stay with the previous line. 

  \end{enumerate}
  Sentence \ref{A} and \ref{B} must appear together.
```

I need something like this without the dots after numbers:

[image]
It changes the format and moves the text to the next line. Also, it produces an error if there is no \item at the beginning of the text. In some parts, I need the numbers to be in the middle of the sentence and not itemized in different lines. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own label counter and use it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{mylabel}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\refstepcounter{mylabel}\label{#1}\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {\arabic{mylabel}};}}

 \circled{A}This is a  sample.  This sentence should \circled{B} 
   stay with the previous line. 

  Sentence \ref{A} and \ref{B} must appear together.
\end{document}
```

`\newcounter{mylabel}` creates a new counter with a name

`\refstepcounter{mylabel}` increments the custom counter in such a way that the next \label will apply to this counter.

`\arabic{mylabel}` display the counter in arabic numbers.

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! :)